# Midpoint of a rectangle with 8 co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, math, formula, discrete-mathematics

I am writing a javascript program to find the midpoint of the rectangle (diagonal lines which intersect in the middle)
I have 8 co-ordinates (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) (x4,y4).
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please share complate of your codes

Answer (score 0):

Just find the average of each coordinate. Because it’s a rectangle, you only need two coordinates. If x1, y1 is opposite x3, y3 then the midpoint is ((x1+x3)/2, (y1+y3)/2)

Comment: Can you kindly simplify more? Here is the list of my coordinates 134.2 = x1
174.1=x2
134.2=x3
174.1 =x4

741.4=y1
741.4=y2
725.6=y3
725.6=y4

Comment: @umzee ((134.2+174.1)/2, (741.4+725.6)/2) = (154.15, 733.5)

Answer (score 0):

Midpoint of a triangle is the midpoint of each diagonal. So, the midpoint is:

```
x_mid = (x1 + x3)/2; // or (x2 + x4)/2
y_mid = (y1 + y3)/2; // or (y2 + y4)/2
```